# How does Grails render views when the files don't exist in the `grails-app/views` directory?

Tags: grails, groovy

If one doesn't have the standard `create.gsp`, `edit.gsp`, `list.gsp`, and `show.gsp` in the `grails-app/views/controllerName` directory, how is Grails rendering the pages? I didn't have these in this default location, and Grails was still rendering the default pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard (i.e. scaffolded) views are provided by Grails and automatically rendered if you haven't created your own (or generated them) in `grails-app/views`.

If you want to see exactly what's being rendered, you can:

```
grails install-templates
```

Running this will put the views into `src/templates` so that you can view and edit them.

[Docs for install-templates.](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html)